# how to vlookup with more than one occurrence

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

Each individual order has either one line item or multiple items

```
 Order ID |  Basket | Price | Province

 22124495 |  STK1C  | 29.94 |   QC

 22124495 |  SBXC   |   -   |   QC

 22124495 |  S8K1C  |   -   |   QC
```

I want to make it look like this in one line but I am not sure how I can do it, I have thousands of rows

```
22124495 | STK1C   | SBXC   |   S8K1C  | 29.94 | - | - | QC
```

Comment: Are the multiple rows with the same Order ID always consecutive/adjacent rows? Also, what is the max number of such rows? Also also, each row has Province = QC in it, but your desired output only shows it once, predictably enough. Which row should this be recovered from? Will multiple rows for an order no always show this as the same?

Answer (score 0):

referring to @KikwiSteve 's questions. If the ID's are in consecutive rows and if there is a maximum number of rows for each ID and if the province is the same for each ID you can use something like this.

It is setup to allow for 4 records for each ID but that can be easily changed. If puts the data in columns such that a column is for a specific field with some columns blank if there is no data for that field.

B12 = =IF(COLUMNS($B12:B12)>COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,$A12),"",INDEX($A$2:$D$6,MATCH($A12,$A$2:$A$6,0)+COLUMNS($B12:B12)-1,2)) - copied over to E12

F12 = =IF(COLUMNS($F12:F12)>COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,$A12),"",INDEX($A$2:$D$6,MATCH($A12,$A$2:$A$6,0)+COLUMNS($F12:F12)-1,3)) - copied over to I12

J12 = =IF(COLUMNS($J12:J12)>COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,$A12),"",INDEX($A$2:$D$6,MATCH($A12,$A$2:$A$6,0)+COLUMNS($J12:J12)-1,4)) - this one probably can be simplified since it just needs to pull the first record.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the ID's are in consecutive rows and there is a maximum of lets just say 15 rows for each ID and the province is the same for each ID. The reason for this exercise is that each ID is an Order and an Order can have multiple items in the basket however one of those line items is this shipping and there's no way of extracting the shipping line besides from identifying them one by one.